# Php display_errors

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to make php show errors, right now all I get is a blank page. I've tried changing the php.ini file that seems to be the php configuration file but to no success. Could it be that phpinfo() is wrong about what config file is been loaded? (I did restart apache)

**phpinfo** Loaded Configuration File  ->   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. I copy-pasted the path and filename so misspelling it is not an issue.

Comment: No it can not be wrong. If you enabled it and if it shows that errors are enabled and if you still don't get any errors, then there are no errors.

Comment: is display_error on in your php.ini file?also try ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

Comment: The in file ini_set works fine. But changing the php.ini file doesn't seem to do anything. Phpinfo() still shows display_errors Off. That's why i'm thinking I'm not changing the correct config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this by using the following code and inside you php.ini file 
display_errors = on

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: A little bit of overkill to set `error_reporting` in *3* different ways and `display_errors` in 2, no?

Comment: display_errors and display_startup_errors are two different settings

Answer (score 4):

Enable error reporting at the top of the php page:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: As of today, this is the only correct answer on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Place this at the top of your page, but be sure to remove it once you have your errors corrected. You don't want the entire world to be able to have insight into your database structure.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```